# Are old users eligible for introductory pricing?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-store, in-app-purchase

We are introducing a free trial using the introductory pricing provided by Apple in StoreKit. The subscription has been available for a long time. My question is, if a user had subscribed before the introduction of Free Trial and has now cancelled the subscription, will this user be eligible for Free Trial now?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app

In the above link, under the subheading **Determine User Eligibility**, in point 2

Will either **Subscription Trial Period** or **Subscription Introductory Price Period** be true for the above user?

Comment: We are not providing free trial on our own. There is an Apple API to check if the user is eligible or not. I'm just asking, what will be the result in such a case.

Comment: @SolarMike OP is the developer, this question is regarding whether *other people* can abuse StoreKit.

Comment: @grg The edit does make it clearer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, yes. Given the [quote from Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app) below (emphasis mine):

> Based on the receipt, you will find that new and returning customers
>   are eligible for introductory price or free trial discounts as
>   follows:
>
> - New subscribers are always eligible.
> - Lapsed subscribers who renew are eligible *if they haven't previously received an introductory price* for the given product (or any product
>     within the same subscription group).

However, do [ask App Store Connect Inquiries](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus) directly. They will be able to provide an absolute and authoritative answer.